# Create 2 triangles using for loop and while loop

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLlqL.png)

Try to print out 2 triangles using for and while loop with n is entered by user.
But the while loop I can't get it to print out the triangle
it should look like this:

```
n = 3
*X
*X X
*X X X
*X
*X X
*X X X
```

but it print out like this

```
X
X X
X X X
X
X
X
X
X
X
```

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Triangle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, number, count=0, count1;

    System.out.print("Please enter an integer number: ");
    n = input.nextInt();

    if (n>0)
    {
       for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
       {    
           for(int j=0; j<i;j++)
           System.out.print(" X");


           System.out.println("");


       }

       while(count<n)
       {   
           count = count +1;
           count1 = 0;
           while(count1 < count)
           {

               System.out.print(" X");
               System.out.println("");

               count1 = count1 + 1;
            }
       }


    }
    else
    {
    System.out.print("Invalid number! Enter the number again!");
    }

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your while loop. You are having the `System.out.println("");` within your inner while loop. Like in the version with the for loop, the `System.out.println("");` should be called after the inner while loop has been processed.

```
while(count<n) //outer
{   
    count = count +1;
    count1 = 0;
    while(count1 < count) //inner
    {
        System.out.print(" X");
        count1 = count1 + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(""); // Thats the right place. 
}
```